# make 2D dict from dict python by splitting keys with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
{'word1/AB': 1,
 'word2/AB': 2,
 'word3/CD': 1,
 'word4/EF': 1,
 'word5/GH': 1}
```

And I need to end up with a 2D dict that looks like this:

```
{'word1':{'AB': 1},
 'word2':{'AB': 2},
 'word3':{'CD': 1},
 'word4':{'EF': 1},
 'word5':{'GH': 1}}
```

My regex for splitting the key is: `"[a-zA-Z]*[^\/]"`

But I'm absolutely stumped on how to go about making this. I believe I have to loop through the dict, split the key to two strings and construct the new dict using {str1:{str2: original dict value}} but my knowledge on dicts and slicing etc is shabby and I can't put my thought in code.

Could you help in determining what "tools" I need to do this?

**Edit:** I had totally forgot about .split(), however this wasn't the most important aspect of the question. Thanks all for reminding me though!

Comment: If you are a beginner in Python you should start with something simpler: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split your string on the `'/'` character, there's no need for regex here.

```
>>> d = {'word1/AB': 1,
...: 'word2/AB': 2,
...: 'word3/CD': 1,
...: 'word4/EF': 1,
...: 'word5/GH': 1}
...: 
>>> result = {}
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...:     k_outer, k_inner = k.split('/')
...:     result[k_outer] = {k_inner:v}
...:     
>>> result
>>> 
{'word1': {'AB': 1},
 'word2': {'AB': 2},
 'word3': {'CD': 1},
 'word4': {'EF': 1},
 'word5': {'GH': 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.split`:

```
d = {'word1/AB': 1, 'word2/AB': 2, 'word3/CD': 1, 'word4/EF': 1, 'word5/GH': 1}
new_data = {tuple(a.split('/')):b for a, b in d.items()}
final_result = {a:{b:c} for [a, b], c in new_data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'word1': {'AB': 1}, 'word2': {'AB': 2}, 'word3': {'CD': 1}, 'word4': {'EF': 1}, 'word5': {'GH': 1}}
```

Comment: so what you're doing in is:

create a dict `new_data = {tuple("word1","AB"):val}`

create a dict `final = { word : { ab : v}}` looping the new_dict and getting the key tuple as a list, and then setting each element were it's supposed to be. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split on a regular expression you could use `re.split(regex, stringToSplit)`:

```
import re
dict = {'word1/AB': 1, 'word2/AB': 2,'word3/CD': 1,'word4/EF': 1,'word5/GH': 1}
dict2d = {}
for key in dict:
    values = re.split("\/", key);
    dict2d[values[0]] = {values[1]:dict[key]}
print dict2d
```

### Output

```
{'word5': {'GH': 1}, 'word4': {'EF': 1}, 'word1': {'AB': 1}, 'word3': {'CD': 1}, 'word2': {'AB': 2}}
```

However, for what you want to achieve i believe that `key.split("\/")` would be more than enough

Answer (score 0):

You can split keys with str.split('/'). This one-liner will work:

```
db = {'word1/AB': 1, 'word2/AB': 2, 'word3/CD': 1, 'word4/EF': 1, 'word5/GH': 1}

{ k.split('/')[0]: {k.split('/')[1]: db[k]}  for k in db.keys()}
```